# Is there a way to include raw URL in http request params?

Tags: http, http-request-parameters

I've got a quick question, is it possible to include raw url in request params? I guess that it is a problem with additional // that confuses Postman, which I am using or I have to create a special request handler in my server.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/https://google.com
```

Here is how I try to handle this in my node.js express server

```
app.use('/api/:url')
```

I know that I can overcome this by changing my api and include this in body, but I want to do this that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to handle this is to use [URL encoding](https://www.urlencoder.org/).

For example, I want to include `http://my-raw-url` as the query param `url` in `http://wrapper.com`. The URL would look like this:

```
http://wrapper.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-raw-url
```

Your backend code will need decode it back. All modern languages have easy-to-use libraries how to do it.